# Select multiple counts for each day in date range using N1QL

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am trying to figure out how to use a Couchbase N1QL query to return the total amount of documents with a given date over a specific date range and return each date as a row with a second column with the total count.

Example Document

```
{
  "userPk": "43da6438-5a17-4b95-b9cb-993788677675",
  "value": "6f916dba-6fa1-42b0-8816-c1e78bdabce5",
  "type": 3,
  "date": "2017-03-14T12:15:05.4407826-05:00",
  "userAgentString": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
}
```

So, essentially I am looking to run one query that is equal to this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bucket1 WHERE `value` = "6f916dba-6fa1-42b0-8816-c1e78bdabce5" AND date = "2017-03-14";
```

but for a seven day period with the results looking something like this:

```
Date       | Total
------------------
2017-03-14 | 1300
2017-03-13 | 1000
2017-03-12 | 1200
2017-03-11 | 1100
2017-03-10 | 1300
2017-03-09 | 1100
2017-03-08 | 1300
```

Is this something N1QL is currently capable of doing?

Answer (score 2):

Easier than I thought...

```
SELECT SUBSTR(date,0,10) As Date, COUNT(1) As Total FROM bucket1 WHERE value= "6f916dba-6fa1-42b0-8816-c1e78bdabce5" AND date BETWEEN "2017-03-01T12:15:05.4407826-05:00" AND "2017-03-31T12:15:05.4407826-05:00" GROUP BY SUBSTR(date,0,10) ;
```